# How to change default id_rsa in github to another?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have created my two differents accounts.
personal and work.
My personal account is connected with github with SSH etc., but I do not know how to change to another host?

```
#Default GitHub
Host personal
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_privatehome

Host work
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

When I commit I have account on the list from `Host work` where I would like to change to `Host personal` and make my things.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Change the repo's remote URL?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33537834/7976758 as an example. In your case it's `git remote set-url origin git@personal:<username>/<reponame>.git`