# multiple github account for multiple ssh key

Tags: git, github, ssh, rsa

I have two github account, one for work and another personal. I have generated two rsa key and put those rsa to the respected account. these are working fine

But everytime I had to run this command `ssh-add ~/.ss/my_work` or `ssh-add ~/.sss/my_personal`

My questions is why I have to run this `ssh-add` command every time once I open new terminal and pull/push something?

I tried to solve it by updating `~/.ssh/config` file but it doesn't work, I found lots of solution on StackOverflow but those are not solved my cases

I followed this: https://gist.github.com/alejandro-martin/aabe88cf15871121e076f66b65306610

Yet, I had to run `ssh-add` command to add the ssh private key of the repo? why it is not adding permantly?

For one reop, it doesn't requires to run `ssh-add` command but another repo, always had to run, otherwise, I am getting following error:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I followed this too: [Multiple GitHub Accounts & SSH Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225862/multiple-github-accounts-ssh-config)

The situation is same, they work only when I run `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` and then `~/.ssh/my_work`

Can anyone please help me to get it done? what is the problem? why I have to every time add `ssh-add` command for another repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My questions is why I have to run this ssh-add command every time once I open new terminal and pull/push something?

You need this only if you have created encrypted private keys (keys protected by a passphrase).

If you did not enter a passphrase when creating said keys, you would not need `ssh-agent` at all.

And if you need `ssh-agent`, you could enter your passphrase once when opening your session, and then keep that session open for your subsequent push/pull/clone operations. Without having to enter the passphrase again, since, in that session, the `ssh-agent` would have cached said passphrase.

You can [automate launching the ssh-agent](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows=).