# Using git with multiple accounts: Error: Permission to user/repo denied to other-user

Tags: git, github

I am trying to set up git with a work account and a personal account. I'm quite new to git.

I am able to push to the work account, but when trying to push to the personal account, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Permission to <personal_repo> denied to <work_github_username>.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

My ssh config looks like this:

```
# Personal account, - the default config
Host github.com-<personal_github_username>
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<name_of_personal_private_key_file>

# Work account
Host github.com-<work_github_username>
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<name_of_work_private_key_file>
```

If I do `git remote -v` I get:
origin  git@github.com:<personal_github_username>/<repo_name>.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:<personal_github_username>/<repo_name>.git.git (push)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3860139/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+multiple+accounts

Comment: Please show your `git remote` for the personal repository. Is the URL `git@github.com-<personal_github_username>` ?

Comment: Note that you will usually want `IdentitiesOnly yes` (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/3225862/1256452).

Comment: `git remote set-url origin git@github.com-<personal_github_username>:<personal_github_username>/<repo_name>.git`

Comment: Thank you @phd ! That works. Do I need to run that every time I made a new repo? Is that the best way to do it?

Comment: @Chessnut For every new repo you do `git init` — yes, either `git@github.com-<personal_github_username>` or `github.com-<work_github_username>`. When you `git clone` just use the proper URL in the command — it'll be stored in `.git/config` so you don't need to change it.

Comment: Thank you @phd! Greatly appreciated. Out of curiosity, what does adding the ending to `git@github.com-<personal_github_username>` do? If I type in github.com<personal_github_username> to the address bar in my browser, it does a regular search, whereas github.com doesn't.

Comment: Git doesn't process the URL, it passes the URL to SSH and SSH looks it up in `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for all your help :) I think I'm good now