# How to permanently add a private key with ssh-add on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, key, ssh-agent

I have a private key protected with a password to access a server via SSH.

I have 2 linux (ubuntu 10.04) machines and the behavior of ssh-add command is different in both of them.

In one machine, once I use "ssh-add .ssh/identity" and entered my password, the key was added permanently, i.e., every time I shutdown the computer and login again, the key is already added.

In the other one, I have to add the key every time I login.

As far as I remember, I did the same thing on both. The only difference is that the key was created on the one that is added permanently.

Does anyone know how to add it permanently to the other machine as well?

Comment: the agent should be temporary only; but it is possible you have the ssh-add command somewhere in ~/.bashrc or so on one of the both machines

Comment: This command worked for me ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: That's what worked for Ubuntu 22.04.2. No password needed after reboots.

`cp key.pub ~/.ssh

cp key ~/.ssh

chmod 600 ~/.ssh/key.pub

chmod 600 ~/.ssh/key`

Answer (score 933, accepted):

A solution would be to force the key files to be kept permanently, by adding them in your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitHubKey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_buhlServer
```

If you do not have a 'config' file in the ~/.ssh directory, then you should create one. It does not need root rights, so simply:

```
nano ~/.ssh/config
```

...and enter the lines above as per your requirements.

For this to work the file needs to have chmod 600. You can use the command `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config`.

If you want all users on the computer to use the key put these lines into `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and the key in a folder accessible to all.

Additionally if you want to set the key specific to one host, you can do the following in your ~/.ssh/config :

```
Host github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/githubKey
```

This has the advantage when you have many identities that a server doesn't reject you because you tried the wrong identities first. Only the specific identity will be tried.

Comment: Permissions on the config file should be 600. ```chmod 600 config```

Comment: I have to put in my password for every push, fetch, or clone with this, how do I avoid that?

Comment: Use instead `ssh-add ~/.ssh/gitHubKey`, it will remember your key passphrase. The solution I proposed was to set it permanently across reboots.

Comment: This answer is so good that ssh-add shouldn't exist. Who wants to have a command that "temporarily" fixes a problem and breaks unexpectedly when you can just edit a config file permanently.

Comment: The problem is with this kind of config, if you don't do it in .ssh/config for a specific Host, you'll get all key tried against all server each time.

Comment: This solution is not using the ssh-agent. - Is there a difference? Yeah, you can't forward they identity via agent-forwarding.

Comment: @daminetreg
How will it know which key to send to which server?
For example, if I have key1<>server1 and key2<>server2, and both are set in ~/.ssh/config.. will it try both keys when connecting?  If yes, isn't it a security issue?

Comment: As mentioned in the reply, if you use the second way which is host specific the key won't be tried on other hosts than the one specified with HostName.
But with the first solution proposed the key will be tried on each host. But it's not an issue as the key is used to encrypt a random challenge message from the server, if the server is able to decrypt it with the public key previously uploaded, then it will let you log in.
So that an attacker could make a plain-text attack on your key, you should log-in **alot** to other servers so that they might begin inducing your key.

Comment: You can clone with @github.com if you put this in your config file:  `Host github.com`

Comment: this worked on mac os sierra too

Comment: If the config file change starts "Host github.com", then you don't need the "HostName" line, and you no longer need to clone using just "github", you can use the regular clone url including "github,com".

Comment: Thanks @JonathanHartley , did it always work or is it an improvement of modern ssh versions ?

Comment: Hi. I don't know.

Comment: Test your connection with `ssh -T git@github.com`

Comment: certainly one of the best answers on the whole site!

Comment: what is the `~/.ssh/config` for?

Comment: @CharlieParker what do you mean ? `~/.ssh/config` is the user-specific SSH client config file. ~ is the home directory of the user and ssh on windows should also look in the user directory for a config as in $HOME/.ssh/config

Comment: Is it me or does this not actually answer the question? The question is how to permanently ssh-add, which would load the key in the agent, which means the key could also be forwarded. With this solution, at least on my computer, the key only works locally. Been running in circles because of this.

Comment: @SFG well this was more of a pragmatic reply, I see on the other upvoted answer that there is on macos the -K flag of ssh-add that can be used with a FIDO authenticator which can be permanent.

At the time of writing the reply I think this wasn't yet possible or definitely personally didn't know about it. I think there might be a setup-involved solution now, but that is then OS specific.

Answer (score 182):

I solved that problem on macOS 10.10 by the `-K` flag in the `ssh-add` command:

```bash
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/your_private_key
```

For macOS 10.12 and later you need to additionally edit your ssh config as described here: https://github.com/jirsbek/SSH-keys-in-macOS-Sierra-keychain

#### 2023 Update

On newer versions on macOS, you have to use the `--apple-use-keychain` flag instead of `-K`, since `-K` is deprecated:

```bash
ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/your_private_key
```

Comment: this is a better answer for people who want to set it permanently

Comment: This doesn't work on CentOS

Comment: Hence this bit: "on Mac OSX (10.10)"...

Comment: This is good and working on Mac OSX, but doesn't work on Ubuntu (14.04 on my testing).

Comment: This didn't work for me (on OSX 10.12.4)

Comment: For me, this only works if the ssh-agent process hasn't been stopped, either manually, or from rebooting.

Comment: According to `man ssh-add` on macOS High Sierra, `ssh-add -K` will save the passphrase into the keychain, and after rebooting, just use `ssh-add -A`, which does not need you to input your passphrase.

Comment: OP specifically asked for help on ubuntu, which is getting buried by this post.https://stackoverflow.com/a/37256434/5109177

Would it be pedantic to ask this get moved to a mac specific thread?

[do those cost extra? :*)]

Comment: In newer versions of MacOS >10.12

in your ~/.ssh/config file add the following

AddKeysToAgent yes
UseKeychain yes

This works fine in Mojave

Comment: How can I refrain from doing this again after every time I restart the system?

Comment: what is the equivalent command for linux or ubuntu? I get `unknown option -- K` (I admit I'm not sure why I even need to do this...)

Comment: `The -K and -A flags are deprecated and have been replaced
         by the --apple-use-keychain and --apple-load-keychain
         flags, respectively. `

Answer (score 132):

This didn't answer the same issue for me under Mac OS X Lion.  I ended up adding:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa &>/dev/null
```

To my .zshrc (but .profile would be fine too), which seems to have fixed it.

(As suggested here: http://geek.michaelgrace.org/2011/09/permanently-add-ssh-key-ssh-add/ )

Comment: This is I think better than the solution I proposed, because ssh-add uses an authentication agent which can remember the passphrase of a protected private key, so that you don't need to type it each time you try to authenticate. Another advantage of the solution you propose is that if you have alot of key, the ssh client won't propose keys irrelevant for the server you try to connect to, indeed it will provide only the keys which are for this server, and won't lead to the server refusing the connection because of MaxAuthTries being reached, while trying all the keys listed in ssh/config.

Comment: Thanks @daminetreg.  My particular problem was needing to access gitosis on a development machine without transferring my private key to it.  This solution (along with adding `ForwardAgent yes` to my `.ssh/config`) solved that issue fantastically.  As it turns out, it could just be `ssh-add &>/dev/null` as the default behavior of `ssh-add` appears to be to add the keys it finds in your `.ssh` folder.

Comment: My understanding is that there is a -K switch in Mac OS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909651/svnssh-not-having-to-do-ssh-add-every-time-mac-os

Comment: @TNick `-K` adds keys to OS X's keychain, which OS X GUIs use to authenticate to foreign servers.  The poster in that Q is connecting through an SSH Tunnel, but is still just connecting to a remote server. **A**-[SSH Tunnel]->B The case I'm in is I am on a remote server but want authentication to be against credentials on my home system.  A <-[Auth]-**B**-[Connect]->C  So `-K` doesn't actually help, but is a great solution for the other Q.

Comment: what is the equivalent command for linux or ubuntu? I get `unknown option -- K` (I admit I'm not sure why I even need to do this...)

Answer (score 62):

Just add the keychain, as referenced in Ubuntu Quick Tips
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/QuickTips

**What**

Instead of constantly starting up ssh-agent and ssh-add, it is possible to use keychain to manage your ssh keys. To install keychain, you can just click here, or use Synaptic to do the job or apt-get from the command line.

**Command line**

Another way to install the file is to open the terminal (Application->Accessories->Terminal) and type:

```
sudo apt-get install keychain
```

**Edit File**

You then should add the following lines to your ${HOME}/.bashrc or /etc/bash.bashrc:

```
keychain id_rsa id_dsa
. ~/.keychain/`uname -n`-sh
```

Comment: What exactly does the second command do, out of curiosity? this just opens the permissions to the current user?

Comment: This `.` is an alias for `source`

Comment: Is the steps enough?  Why the file   ~/.keychain/`uname -n`-sh  exists ?

Comment: what's `id_dsa` ?  I've searched this page and only seen this mentioned in this answer and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35176183/227926)  but not in the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466626/how-to-permanently-add-a-private-key-with-ssh-add-on-ubuntu). Is this just another key like `id_rsa` because 2 keys are being setup?

Comment: When using this method, on opening a first terminal I'm asked for my passphrase.

Comment: I am curious if keychain saves the ssh key passphrase and how does it do that. Where are these passphrases saved?

Comment: what is the equivalent command for linux or ubuntu? I get `unknown option -- K` (I admit I'm not sure why I even need to do this...)

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, replace id_rsa with the name of your private key file. And remove the second id_rsa.

Answer (score 25):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04: some keys were added permanently, for others I had to execute `ssh-add` on every session. I found out that the keys which were added permanently had both private and public key located in `~/.ssh` and the keys which were forgotten on every session had only private keys in `~/.ssh` dir. So solution is simple: you should copy **both** private and public key to `~/.ssh` before executing `ssh-add`.

**P.S.:** As far as I understand from [Gnome wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Ssh) my method works thanks to gnome-keyring tool which is part of the Gnome Desktop Environment. Therefore my method should probably work only if you use Gnome or Gnome-based DE.

Comment: Underrated answer. This solved my problem without needing additional scripts or packages after searching for two hours.

Comment: Flarkin fabulous! Great detective work. I don't think I would have figured this out.

Comment: For me this was the solution too! You do not need any other software or installations or configuration. Just put both keys in.

Comment: Although this might work I would suggest that putting the public and private key in the same place is a very bad idea - it's like leaving the keys in the car

Comment: This worked for me. @OliverDungey I would agree and disagree. At the end of the day unless you are storing the private key off the computer (say a flash drive) since it is in your directory another sudo user / root could access the file no matter where it is with the find command. If you are the only one on the system and have a strong password I don't see this as a risk.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04. GREAT

Answer (score 20):

I tried @Aaron's solution and it didn't quite work for me, because it would re-add my keys every time I opened a new tab in my terminal. So I modified it a bit(note that most of my keys are also password-protected so I can't just send the output to /dev/null):

```
added_keys=`ssh-add -l`

if [ ! $(echo $added_keys | grep -o -e my_key) ]; then
    ssh-add "$HOME/.ssh/my_key"
fi
```

What this does is that it checks the output of `ssh-add -l`(which lists all keys that have been added) for a specific key and if it doesn't find it, then it adds it with `ssh-add`.

Now the first time I open my terminal I'm asked for the passwords for my private keys and I'm not asked again until I reboot(or logout - I haven't checked) my computer.

Since I have a bunch of keys I store the output of `ssh-add -l` in a variable to improve performance(at least I guess it improves performance :) )

PS: I'm on linux and this code went to my `~/.bashrc` file - if you are on Mac OS X, then I assume you should add it to `.zshrc` or `.profile`

EDIT:
As pointed out by @Aaron in the comments, the `.zshrc` file is used from the `zsh` shell - so if you're not using that(if you're not sure, then most likely, you're using `bash` instead), this code should go to your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: `.zshrc` is for the `zsh` shell, which I use instead of `bash`.  If you're using `bash` on Mac OS X (the default), it would be `.bashrc` there as well.

Comment: After `ssh-add -l` return code `echo $?` can be used to decide whether to add key or not. Im my linux machine with bash, the `ssh-add -l` won't output the key filename. Return code always works.

Answer (score 15):

In my case the solution was:

> Permissions on the config file should be 600. `chmod 600 config`

As mentioned in the comments above by
 generalopinion

No need to touch the config file contents.

Comment: Was not enough for me on Linux Mint 17.1.

Comment: I don't think 600 makes sense. [man ssh](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh) tells us that the `~/.ssh/config` file read/write for the user, and not writable by others.

Comment: 600 is read and write only for the user

Answer (score 6):

I run Ubuntu using two id_rsa key's. (one personal one for work). 
ssh-add would remember one key (personal one) and forget the company one every time.

Checking out the difference between the two I saw my personal key had 400 rights while the company one had 600 rights. (had u+w). 
Removing the user write right from the company key (u-w or set to 400) fixed my problem. ssh-add now remembers both keys.

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 14.04 (maybe earlier, maybe still) you don't even need the console:

- start `seahorse` or launch that thing you find searching for "key"
- create an SSH key there (or import one)

  - no need to leave the passphrase empty
  - it is offered to you to even push the public key to a server (or more)
- you will end up with an ssh-agent running and this key loaded, but locked
- using `ssh` will pickup the identity (i.e. key) through the agent
- on first use during the session, the passphrase will be checked

  - and you have the option to automatically unlock the key on login
  - this means the login auth will be used to wrap the passphrase of the key
- *note: if you want to forward your identity (i.e. agent-forwarding) invoke your `ssh` with `-A` or make that the default*

  - otherwise you can't authenticate with that key *on a machine you login to later to a third machine*

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 is still using `seahorse`.

Answer (score 4):

Adding the following lines in "~/.bashrc" solved the issue for me. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 desktop.

```
eval `gnome-keyring-daemon --start`
USERNAME="reynold"
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$(ls /run/user/$(id -u $USERNAME)/keyring*/ssh|head -1)"
export SSH_AGENT_PID="$(pgrep gnome-keyring)"
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

```
ssh-agent /bin/sh
ssh-add /path/to/your/key
```

Comment: This works for me at Ubuntu 22.04 . Added this to my ~/.bashrc:

  eval `keychain --quiet --eval --agents ssh $HOME/.ssh/sinyavskijjds.key``

Answer (score 4):

For those that use Fish shell you can use the following function then call it in `~/.config/fish/config.fish` or in a separate configuration file in `~/.config/fish/conf.d/loadsshkeys.fish`. It will load all keys that start with **id_rsa** into the `ssh-agent`.

```
# Load all ssh keys that start with "id_rsa"
function loadsshkeys
  set added_keys (ssh-add -l)
   for key in (find ~/.ssh/ -not -name "*.pub" -a -iname "id_rsa*")
    if test ! (echo $added_keys | grep -o -e $key)
      ssh-add "$key"
    end
  end
end

# Call the function to run it.
loadsshkeys
```

If you want to have the `ssh-agent` auto started when you open a terminal you can use  [danhper/fish-ssh-agent](https://github.com/danhper/fish-ssh-agent) to do this.

Comment: Thanks, the repo link seems to be redirecting to https://github.com/danhper/fish-ssh-agent now.

Comment: Thanks @ElijahLynn! I edited my answer and updated the repository link.

Answer (score 3):

very simple  ^_^  two steps

1.yum install keychain

2.add code below to .bash_profile

```
/usr/bin/keychain $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa
source $HOME/.keychain/$HOSTNAME-sh
```

Comment: Ubuntu Doesn't have yum silly ;)