# How to combine multiple vars files per host?

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook running against multiple servers. All servers require a `sudo` password to be specified, which is specific to each user running the playbook. When running the playbook, I can't use `--ask-become-pass`, because the sudo passwords on the servers differ. This is the same situation as in [another question about multiple sudo passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33157327/1023963).

A working solution is to specify `ansible_become_pass` in `host_vars`:

```
# host_vars/prod01.yml
ansible_become_pass: secret_prod01_password
domain: prod01.example.com
```

```
# host_vars/prod02.yml
ansible_become_pass: secret_prod02_password
domain: prod02.example.com
```

Besides `ansible_become_pass`, there are other variables defined per host. These variables should be committed to the git repository. However, as `ansible_become_pass` is specific to each user running the playbook, I'd like to have a separate file (ideally, vaulted) which specifies the password per host.

I imagine the following:

```
# host_vars/prod01.yml: shared in git
domain: prod01.example.com
```

```
# host_vars/prod01_secret.yml: in .gitignore
ansible_become_pass: secret_prod01_password
```

I imagine both files to be combined by Ansible when running the playbook. Is this possible in Ansible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also just have a directory for each host and multiple variable files in that, like

```
host_vars/host1/vars.yaml
host_vars/host1/secret_vars.yaml
```

The same works for groups, too. See docs for more: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the *include_vars* task with the *inventory_hostname* or *ansible_hostname* variable.  For example:

```
- name: Include host specific variables
  include_vars: "{{ ansible_hostname }}.yml"

- name: Include host specific secret variables
  include_vars: "{{ ansible_hostname }}_secret.yml"
```

An even better solution would be to address the problem of users having unique passwords on different hosts.

Comment: What would you suggest as a solution to the problem of specific passwords for every user? Isn't it generally more secure to have personal `sudo` passwords?

Comment: It might technically be more secure to have a different password on each system, but this is unmanageable and is an anti-pattern.  Typically, your sudo password is your user password, which should be a domain password.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new group in the inventory file, maybe sudo-hosts. Put all your sudo host in this group. Then create a file under the directory group_vars with the name of this goup. In this file put the secret yaml-structured text.

```
sudo_hosts:
  host1:
    password: xyz
    othersecret_stuff: abc
  host2:
    ...
```

then use `ansbile-vault` to encrypt this file with ONE password. Call the playbook with option `--ask-vault-pass`
and you can use your secrets with

`"{{ sudo_host['ansible_host'].password }}"`

Comment: Beside this solution, you could use public-key authentication and passwordless sudo. Also a strong passphrase on the private key and it is very secure.