# SSH issue: Codeship-run deploy script on my server is failing to pull from Github

Tags: github, deployment, ssh, public-key, codeship

I have my repo hooked up to Codeship which runs tests and then finally runs a script on my server via SSH:

```
ssh deploy@my.server '/var/www/deploy-script.sh'
```

On my server I have my `deploy` user set up. I have that user's public key stored on my github account. I also have the codeship public key for my project stored in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Inside `deploy-script.sh`, I'm navigating to the repo directory and then trying `git pull`. Obviously, I need the latest code to be pulled down without a password as this is being run on a virtual machine on codeship. Codeship is apparently able to SSH into my server and run the deployment script, however the log is reporting:

```
> Pull updates from Github.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

If I log into my server as the `deploy` user and run the script fine, with the `git pull` working correctly.

What am I missing? Why doesn't github allow access when it's codeship logging in as the deploy user rather than me?

Answer (score 1):

It seems I overlooked that `ssh-agent` was not persisting between login sessions, so the next time I logged in as the deploy user I also got the permission denied error. I had to `ssh-add` again before my identity was added and I could pull from github. In order to make it persist, I followed the instructions here: [Add private key permanently with ssh-add on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466626/add-private-key-permanently-with-ssh-add-on-ubuntu)

Added the following to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/deploy-key
```