# add ssh key once per login instead of once per bash

Tags: bash, ssh, ssh-agent

I want to use ssh passwordless-login using authentication-key-pairs.

I added

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_p_key
```

to `~/.profile`. **This doesn't work.** If I use the `~/.bashrc` it works fine.

Why do I have to set this every time I call a bash instead of every time the user logges in. I could not find any explanation.

Is there no better way to configure this?

Comment: What lines did you add? Setting `SSH_AGENT_PID` should be enough once the agent is working and knows the passphrase.

Comment: ``eval `ssh-agent -s``  `ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_p_key`

Comment: If you modified `~/.profile`, did you re-login before trying once more?

Comment: I did a reboot after each change on my profile-configuration-files. Do you know if this should work if it's setup correctly?

Answer (score 3):

The answer below solved my problem and for me it looks like a very legit solution.

[Add private key permanently with ssh-add on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466626/add-private-key-permanently-with-ssh-add-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

The

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

sets the environment of the process. If you are using a window manager e.g. on a linux machine then the window manager will likely have a possibility to run a program like e.g. your ssh-agent on startup and passing the environment down to all processes started there, so all your terminal windows/tabs will allow you a passwordless login. The exact location, configuration and behaviour depends on the desktop/wm used.

If you are on a non-window-system, then you might look at the output of the ssh-agent call and paste that into all shells you open, however that may be as complicated as entering your password. The output will likely set something like

```
SSH_AGENT_PID=4041
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-WZANnlaFiaBt/agent.3966
```

and you can access pw-less in all places where you set these

Comment: You can also check for a running ssh-agent and set the variables based on its PID automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding "IdentityFile ~/.ssh/config" to my .ssh/config did not work for me. I had to also add "AddKeysToAgent yes" to that file.

I think this extra line is necessary because gnome-Keyring loads my key but it has a bug that prevents it from being forwarded to the machine I ssh into.

Edit: After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, new terminals that I started could not access the ssh-agent. I had to add `eval (ssh-agent -c) &>/dev/null` to my `~/.config/fish/config.fish` file.