# Git create multi-user for GitLab and GitHub

Tags: git, github, gitlab, multi-user

In Windows env, I need to create multi-user git account for GitLab(company) and GitHub(personal), I configured the config file under .ssh folder, but I have to execute following two command every time manually when I wanna use company account.

```
ssh-agent bash
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_company
```

is there any way to add the id_rsa_company to SSH session permanently. I searched that ssh default id_rsa file.

Comment: Are your ssh private keys passphrase protected? If not, you don't need ssh-agent.

Comment: yep, it's proctected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any sort of BASH emulation in Windows? Are you using Cygwin?

1. If you can use real BASH ([which has been recently introduced into Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/265900/everything-you-can-do-with-windows-10s-new-bash-shell/)), you can add such command to your `~/.bashrc` file (where `~` is a shorthand for your home directory).
2. Alternatively you can add the keys to the identity file, in the solution [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4246809/542553).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I use Git Bash, and following is my config file content: [link](http://7xkyc7.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/stackOverFlow_1.png),

Comment: I know after configuring the config, I can clone by typing git clone git@host:username/project.git,  how to pull/push specify branch by using git@hostXXXXXXX