# How do I make my SSH settings stick for my repository on macOS?

Tags: git

Every time I restart, I need to execute `ssh-add`, or `git fetch` will fail and give me a "permission denied" message.  How do I solve it?

Comment: Lots of questions to ask here:  first, what are you connecting to - a private repository in a company, or GitHub/Bitbucket/GitLab?  Do you have more than one key defined on your system that could cause the confusion?

Comment: it is a private repository in company,and i do not have more than on key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On mac, you can use `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/your_private_key`

If not, you need to add that step in `~/.profile`.
You have other alternatives detailed in "[Add private key permanently with ssh-add on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3466626/6309)" which might apply to MacOS as well.