# Take pull from bitbucket without password prompt

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, bitbucket, rsa

I want to take pull from my bitbucket repo without asking the password every time. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Steps,

```
$ssh-keygen
```

It generated two key files, `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`

Then, in the Bitbucket repo settings, I have added the ssh key of the server.

```
$cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

But it is not working. It is still asking for password.

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466626/add-private-key-permanently-with-ssh-add-on-ubuntu?rq=1) be of any use? I hope so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the key file in `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host bitbucket.org
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I also added key `id_rsa.pub` in the bitbucket repo. It is working fine now.

Comment: your `HostName` entry looks redundant and I'd suggest using `ssh-add` as suggested by Sascha Effert

Comment: @SamMason ssh-add works but when you relog into server you have to do ssh-add again. Not very helpful unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

The problem could also be that the ssh-agent is not using the key yet. I had this once and spend some time not mentioning this. Please try to run

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and than try again to checkout...

Answer (score 1):

Bitbucket have a pretty good [tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html) explaining how to set up an ssh key.

If you have carefully follwed this (especially the ssh-agent part), maybe you need to update your config.

In your cloned repo you have a .git folder with a config file Inside. Open it and check that you have an ssh url.

You should see somehing like :

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://git@bitbucket.org:<username>/<repoName>.git
```

Here another bitbucket [tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/change-the-remote-url-to-your-repository-794212774.html) that explained it.