# git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. on cloud 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, deployment, vps, ubuntu-server

I am trying to deploy a rails site online using the steps in https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/18.04 but when I run `cap production deploy` I receive, What can I do to fix it please, I am using aws cloud 9

````
deploy@93.188.163.140's password:
00:00 git: wrapper
      01 mkdir -p /tmp
    ✔ 01 deploy@X.X.X.X 0.158s
      Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-young-production-ubuntu.sh 100.0%
      02 chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-young-production-ubuntu.sh
    ✔ 02 deploy@93.188.163.140 0.156s
00:00 git:check
      01 git ls-remote git@github.com:oomis/young.git HEAD
      01 Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.113.4' to the list of known hosts.
      01 git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
      01 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
      01
      01 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
      01 and the repository exists.
#<Thread:0x0000564f38e1cb38@/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
        13: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'

.```

I expect it to deploy my app, how can I fix this, please
````

Comment: did you create a ssh key for your repository???

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by ssh key. Please refer to this official GitHub docs [page](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)
on how to generate one if you haven't. If you already have ssh, add ssh identity from your local machine terminal,

`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Note that this will only add identity for one time deployment and you will need to add again each time the terminal or machine is rebooted.I am not sure what local machine you are using. This stack [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466626/how-to-permanently-add-a-private-key-with-ssh-add-on-ubuntu/4246809#4246809) might help how to add ssh permanently
to your machine.