# Problems when using git with ssh

Tags: git, github, ssh

Whenever I start a session on my PC and try to `git fetch` my remote repository, I get this error:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What I do each time, then, is execute the following commands:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github -T git@github.com
```

Once I've executed the commands above, `git fetch` finally works properly. However, I don't want to repeat the same steps over and over again every time I turn my PC on. How do I solve this issue? I've already tried putting those three commands inside `~/.bashrc`, but that doesn't work.

In case you're wondering, I already added an SSH key to my GitHub account pasting the contents of the public key `~/.ssh/id_rsa_github.pub`, but I still have that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
host github.com
 HostName github.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github
```

to your ssh config file (located at `~/.ssh/config`)

If you want to specify the identity for each git repo individually, you can modify the ssh command for that specific repo:

```
git config core.sshCommand 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github'
```

*(run this command from inside the git repository dir)*

Comment: What if I have more than one private key (one for each different GitHub account)?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can set an individual identity for each git repo.

Comment: That config option is exactly what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: In addition to that, seems like in the Mac you can configure to [avoid having to type the passphrase every time](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent). Just be careful when choosing the host (work vs personal).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the keys are getting lost each time you start a session. You need to add the keys permanently to your agent. For reference on adding the key permanently, you can check the following link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4246809/12680971

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable, **SSH_AUTH_SOCK**, will be set when ssh-agent initiates. So something like this in your **.bashrc** would be a good idea:

```
[ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

This will start a new ssh-agent in the background if it is not already running.

Further, in your **~/.ssh/config** file you should have something like [this](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#AddKeysToAgent):

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

This should add all your loaded keys to your ssh-agent as if you were running ssh-add to every key.