# Moving from https to ssh on GITHUB

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have looked up other questions but do not get the same results the answers have provided.

I initially had my DigitalOcean droplet backed up with a github repo using https.

I have followed all of the instructions (multiple times) at https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/about-ssh

I have deleted the old .git folder.
I have updated the ~/.ssh/config file according to:
[How to permanently add a private key with ssh-add on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466626/how-to-permanently-add-a-private-key-with-ssh-add-on-ubuntu)

Everytime I push or 'git push --set-upstream origin main' I get the option to input my username and password and then get rejected for using https.

I have also updated my ~/.ssh/config file to:

```
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/yourPrivateKeyName
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Comment: Did you change the remote URL to use SSH instead of HTTPS? Doesn't sound like you did

Comment: Git repositories are not a good way to do backups, and GitHub is not going to appreciate you using their service for backups.  You'd be better off using a real backup solution (e.g., bup or Tarsnap) that is designed to do backups in an efficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move from https to ssh, you just need a

```sh
# replace <your-name> and <your-repo> with the real values.
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<your-name>/<your-repo>.git
```

However, to make it easy, you can just clone a new local repo.

Just type

```sh
# replace <your-name> and <your-repo> with the real values.
git clone git@github.com:<your-name>/<your-repo>.git my-new-local-repo
```

[image]