# Create ssh key for github

Tags: ssh

I was created a SSH-key for my first GitHub account, and for some reasons I just use the second account. So I created a SSH-key for the new, but there was some problems on connecting with my GitHub account. I create a SSH key for the new account and add private SSH key to my SSH server, but next time I open a new terminal, I should add the SSH key again or I can not do some remote commands on my remote rep.

When I push my rep to remote, the bash will prompt　: not authenticated
But I'm sure I had add the new ssh-key to the github account now I using. So I add the id_rsa to the ssh server.

```
ssh-add /c/Users/YOU/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

But when I closed this terminal, next time I open a new terminal, this prompt will show again, and I should enter them command again.

I want just enter this command once and later I can never use this command, What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to permanently add a private key with ssh-add on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466626/how-to-permanently-add-a-private-key-with-ssh-add-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is only for questions about _writing code_. Questions about using UNIX tools as a user are better suited to [unix.se].

Comment: Also, if this is _just_ for one server, you can specify in your `~/.ssh/config` that this specific key should be used for this specific server, without using an agent at all.

Comment: OK, the first url is worked, thanks!