# Xcode 4 version control with SVN repository using private/public key

Tags: ios, xcode, svn, private-key

I just wonder if that's possible to use Xcode's version control to connect to SVN repository using svn+ssh protocol with private keys. If it is, can someone please give me some tutorials.
 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: This might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909651/svnssh-not-having-to-do-ssh-add-every-time-mac-os

Do you have your ssh keys working at the moment?  If so does typing ssh-add from the command line let XCode submit without you needing to type the password?  Are the usernames the same between your local install and the remote system you wish to submit to?  What you want to do should 'just work' if it works on the command line.

Comment: I have a remote system + ssh keys set up.  The key has a passphrase.  I open a terminal before working and type ssh-add plus my passphrase.  From then on all is funky dory.

Comment: Oh! Wasn't expecting that.  I'll add it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help

[SVN+SSH, not having to do ssh-add every time? (Mac OS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909651/)

Do you have your ssh keys working at the moment?  If so, as per the above question try typing  "svn-add" from the command line, and entering any pass phrase required.  If that works all is well.