# How to use ssh agent forwarding with "vagrant ssh"?

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, forwarding, ssh-keys, vagrant

Rather than create a new SSH key pair on a vagrant box, I would like to re-use the key pair I have on my host machine, using [agent forwarding](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html). I've tried setting [config.ssh.forward_agent](http://vagrantup.com/v1/docs/config/ssh/forward_agent.html) to TRUE in the Vagrantfile, then rebooted the VM, and tried using:

```
vagrant ssh -- -A
```

...but I'm still getting prompted for a password when I try to do a git checkout. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: if you don't have your ssh keys properly, git should not ask a password, but tell you that you have denied permissions.
I guess you're being asked for a password because you're clonning from https instead of git@github.com (ssh).
my 2 cents.

Answer (score 90):

I'm using vagrant 2 on OS X Mountain Lion.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
end
```

1. `config.ssh.private_key_path` is your local private key
2. Your private key must be available to the local ssh-agent. You can check with `ssh-add -L`, if it's not listed add it with `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
3. Don't forget to add you public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the Vagrant VM. You can do  it copy-and-pasting or using a tool like [ssh-copy-id](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id)

Comment: I noticed that after I set up above, I can use "vagrant" user to "git clone" but I can not use "root" user to "git clone". Do you know what seem to be the issue? Thanks

Comment: I happened to get errors with vm's coming up when I added '.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/id_rsa"'. Forward Agent seemed to work --Vagrant 1.4.2, VirtualBox 4.3.6, on Fedora 3.12.10-300.fc20.x86_64

Comment: `config.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/id_rsa"` makes Vagrant hang on `Waiting for VM to boot`.

Comment: You need to also keep the vagrant insercure key `config.ssh.private_key_path = [ '~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key', '~/.ssh/id_rsa' ]`

Comment: On OS X, I found adding the private keys to the OS X key chain with `ssh-add -K` worked (as well as `config.ssh.forward_agent = true`). [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11673152/247696)

Comment: ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa also did the trick for me on OSX.
user -K if you want to add permanently to keychan.

Comment: I got the same error as @apennebaker . and following the steps that Calin suggested didn't help... 
What worked for me was adding keys to keychain from my host OS and disabling config.ssh.private_key_path assignment.

Comment: @NamNguyen Did you figure out how to clone as "root"?

Comment: @Usha, I haven't figured that out yet

Comment: @NamNguyen I figured it out yesterday,. vagrant ssh <node>, would ssh as vagrant user and then doing a sudo to root made it and took away the public key forwarding. But directly sshing into the node as the required user (root or diffuser) like, ssh -p 2222 diffuser@localhost would forward the public keys.

Comment: ssh-add was the missing part for me.  Super helpful.

Answer (score 84):

Add it to the Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
   # stuff
   config.ssh.forward_agent = true
end
```

[See the docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html#config-ssh-forward_agent)

Comment: Make sure you ssh-add on the underlying host and the key is decrypted.

Comment: Note that Windows does not auto-start ssh-agent, which you need to have running to forward your ssh keys. Follow [this guide](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases]) to setup ssh-agent autostarting on Windows.

Comment: This answer probably doesn't deserve so many votes. OP clearly states they added `config.ssh.forward_agent` to their config file, so what new information is this answer providing? Even the link is already in the question.

Comment: @Trindaz you're complete right. I can't explain why this is one of my most popular answers.

Yet this seemingly helped at least 52 people, so I have to call that a win.

Comment: This answer indeed does not bring any new information, but on the other hand it is everything that needs to be configured for a Vagrant-provisioned machine. At least provided you have agent forwarding set up correctly on the connecting machine (ie. forwarding works for other, non-vagrant machines).

Answer (score 20):

In addition to adding "config.ssh.forward_agent = true" to the vagrant file make sure the host computer is set up for agent forwarding. Github provides a [good guide](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-agent-forwarding) for this. (Check out the troubleshooting section).

Answer (score 7):

I had this working with the above replies on 1.4.3, but stopped working on 1.5.  I now have to run `ssh-add` to work fully with 1.5.

For now I add the following line to my ansible provisioning script.

    `- name: Make sure ssk keys are passed to guest.
      local_action: command ssh-add`

I've also created a gist of my setup: https://gist.github.com/KyleJamesWalker/9538912

Comment: I've always had to use ssh-add with 1.4 and 1.5 as otherwise there was no agent running to be forwarded

Answer (score 5):

If you are on Windows, SSH Forwarding in Vagrant does not work properly by default (because of a bug in net-ssh). See this particular Vagrant bug report: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1735

However, there is a workaround! Simply auto-copy your local SSH key to the Vagrant VM via a simple provisioning script in your VagrantFile. Here's an example:
https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1735#issuecomment-25640783

Answer (score 2):

When we recently tried out the `vagrant-aws` plugin with Vagrant 1.1.5, we ran into an issue with SSH agent forwarding.  It turned out that Vagrant was forcing `IdentitiesOnly=yes` without an option to change it to `no`.  This forced Vagrant to only look at the private key we listed in the `Vagrantfile` for the AWS provider.

I wrote up our experiences in [a blog post](http://www.benjaminoakes.com/2013/04/10/ssh-agent-forwarding-with-vagrant-aws/).  It may turn into a pull request at some point.

Comment: Is there a way to automate copying the underlaying public key on the host machine to the Vagrant VM on creation with `Vagrant up`? Right now I have to create the machine, manually log in and then add my public key to /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the VM does not launch its own SSH agent. I had this line in my `~/.profile`

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

After removing it, SSH agent forwarding worked.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is Vagrant using 127.0.0.1:2222 as default port-forward.
You can add one (not 2222, 2222 is already occupied by default)

**config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host:2333, host_ip: "0.0.0.0"**

"0.0.0.0" is way take request from external connection.
then 
ssh -p 2333 vagrant@192.168.2.101 (change to your own host ip address, dud)
will working just fine. 
Do thank me, Just call me Leifeng!

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, the problem is that Vagrant doesn't know how to communicate with git-bash's ssh-agent. It does, however, know how to use PuTTY's Pageant. So, as long as Pageant is running and has loaded your SSH key, and as long as you've set config.ssh.forward_agent, this should work.

See [this comment](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/1735#issuecomment-25640783) for details.

If you use Pageant, then the [workaround of updating the Vagrantfile to copy SSH keys on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24743876/25507) is no longer necessary.