# Vagrant ssh forward_agent without entering vagrant user password repeadley

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I currently use Vagrant and Chef to provision a VM and setup my PHP based project. This includes running composer install which essentially does a git clone of a number of private repositories.

After setting up ssh agent forwarding as outlined in the docs and the answers here: [How to use ssh agent forwarding with "vagrant ssh"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955525/how-to-use-ssh-agent-forwarding-with-vagrant-ssh) I have successfully got it working.

The problem I'm having is when ever I boot a VM, provision a VM or SSH into a VM I'm now asked for vagrants default password, see examples below:

```
==> web: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
web: SSH address: 192.168.77.185:22
web: SSH username: vagrant
web: SSH auth method: private key
Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.
vagrant@192.168.77.185's password:
```

Example 2

```
➜  vagrant git:(master) ✗ vagrant ssh
vagrant@192.168.77.185's password:
```

This is pretty inconvenient as I work across a number of projects, including destroying and creating some a number of times a day (Chef test kitchen). Is there anyway to automatically use my public key as well so I don't need to continually enter a password?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue recently after creating a new Vagrant box from scratch. The problem turned out to be old entries in ~/.ssh/known_hosts (on OS X).

Try the following (assumes OS X or linux):

1. ssh into your Vagrant machine
2. type `ip addr` or `ifconfig` or the like (depending on your OS)
3. take note of the IP addresses listed, including 127.0.0.1
4. on your host machine, run `ssh-keygen -R {vm-ip-address}` (make sure to include 127.0.0.1 and [127.0.0.1]) for the addresses in step 3
5. confirm the relevant entries have been removed from ~/.ssh/known_hosts
6. vagrant reload
7. vagrant ssh

Alternatively, you can just delete/move/rename the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file, though this will require reconfirming authenticity again for multiple machines you've already ssh'd to.

I hope that helps.

Reference: http://www.geekride.com/ssh-warning-remote-host-identification-has-changed/