# I really need to create each time I have new machine (virtual or not, vagrant, ...) an SSH key for GitHub

Tags: git, ssh, vagrant

On my GitHub configuration there are some SSH keys. One from my personal computer. One from job computer. One from my parents computer and so on. Now, ... that I am starting again a new configuration "session", I am in front of a Vagrant machine. I can create ssh keys and paste it to GitHub. But, ... I already have ssh keys in my HOST. How can I provide unique personal key for my own vagrants? Can I create my personal key? Obviously, ... I don't want a public share of this key. Which are best practices for this? If I share my vagrant machine, ... how can other developers fix SSH keys with their keys?

Finally, ... how is possibile to automate the provisioning of SSH keys inside a vagrang machine?

Comment: you have tried generating the key and adding it directly via terminal?

Comment: I already know this. I need to solve the problem to generate keys every times ...

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955525/how-to-use-ssh-agent-forwarding-with-vagrant-ssh

Comment: Is your problem having to generate new ssh keys every time you boot up a fresh vm? The answer to the question linked above should work in that case. Can you clarify what you mean by unique personal key for my own vagrants? If you want to use different keys for each machine you will have to add them to github.