# Can't SSH into Vagrant (Ubuntu 12.04.5)

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtualbox, ssh-keys, private-key

I just installed Vagrant into host - Ubuntu 12.04.5
The thing is that i am able to start the virtual machine but can't ssh into the machine
everytime i trying ssh'ng into the virtual machine it just can't login.

Now, I am sure that it has something to do with the Vagrant file configuration and the ssh keys but i don't know what i am doing wrong. Please take a look at the Vagrantfile.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
# All Vagrant configuration is done here. The most common configuration
# options are documented and commented below. For a complete reference,
# please see the online documentation at vagrantup.com.

# Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/precise64"

# Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
# boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
# `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
# config.vm.box_check_update = false

# Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
# within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
# accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
 config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

# Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
# using a specific IP.
# config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

# Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
# Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
# your network.
# config.vm.network "public_network"

# If true, then any SSH connections made will enable agent forwarding.
# Default value: false
 config.ssh.forward_agent = true

# Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
# the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
# argument is a set of non-required options.
# config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

# Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
# backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
# Example for VirtualBox:
#
# config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
#   # Don't boot with headless mode
#   vb.gui = true
#
#   # Use VBoxManage to customize the VM. For example to change memory:
#   vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
# end
#
# View the documentation for the provider you're using for more
# information on available options.

# Enable provisioning with CFEngine. CFEngine Community packages are
# automatically installed. For example, configure the host as a
# policy server and optionally a policy file to run:
#
# config.vm.provision "cfengine" do |cf|
#   cf.am_policy_hub = true
#   # cf.run_file = "motd.cf"
# end
#
# You can also configure and bootstrap a client to an existing
# policy server:
#
# config.vm.provision "cfengine" do |cf|
#   cf.policy_server_address = "10.0.2.15"
# end

# Enable provisioning with Puppet stand alone.  Puppet manifests
# are contained in a directory path relative to this Vagrantfile.
# You will need to create the manifests directory and a manifest in
# the file default.pp in the manifests_path directory.
#
# the file default.pp in the manifests_path directory.
#
# config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
#   puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
#   puppet.manifest_file  = "site.pp"
# end

# Enable provisioning with chef solo, specifying a cookbooks path, roles
# path, and data_bags path (all relative to this Vagrantfile), and adding
# some recipes and/or roles.
#
# config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
#   chef.cookbooks_path = "../my-recipes/cookbooks"
#   chef.roles_path = "../my-recipes/roles"
#   chef.data_bags_path = "../my-recipes/data_bags"
#   chef.add_recipe "mysql"
#   chef.add_role "web"
#
#   # You may also specify custom JSON attributes:
#   chef.json = { :mysql_password => "foo" }
# end

# Enable provisioning with chef server, specifying the chef server URL,
# and the path to the validation key (relative to this Vagrantfile).
#
# The Opscode Platform uses HTTPS. Substitute your organization for
# ORGNAME in the URL and validation key.
#
# If you have your own Chef Server, use the appropriate URL, which may be
# HTTP instead of HTTPS depending on your configuration. Also change the
# validation key to validation.pem.
#
# config.vm.provision "chef_client" do |chef|
#   chef.chef_server_url = "https://api.opscode.com/organizations/ORGNAME"
#   chef.validation_key_path = "ORGNAME-validator.pem"
# end
#
# If you're using the Opscode platform, your validator client is
# ORGNAME-validator, replacing ORGNAME with your organization name.
#
# If you have your own Chef Server, the default validation client name is
# chef-validator, unless you changed the configuration.
#
#   chef.validation_client_name = "ORGNAME-validator"
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.customize ['modifyvm', :'11b4ce4e-f322-4d2e-affb-d31f306bdd53', '--pae', 'on']
      vb.customize ['modifyvm', :'11b4ce4e-f322-4d2e-affb-d31f306bdd53', '--hwvirtex', 'off']
      vb.customize ['modifyvm', :'11b4ce4e-f322-4d2e-affb-d31f306bdd53', '--vtxvpid', 'off']
  end
  Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
      config.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
      config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  end
```

end

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: you may find some helpful suggestions in [How to use ssh agent forwarding with “vagrant ssh”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955525/how-to-use-ssh-agent-forwarding-with-vagrant-ssh)