# MacOS Terminal: how to use a seccond ssh key?

Tags: macos, git, ssh, terminal

I'm working on MacOS and want an SSH/Git login with a seccond ssh-key.
I have two key pairs in ~/.ssh/

```
id_rsa
id_rsa.pub
id_rsa.gitlab
id_rsa.gitlab.pub
```

id_rsa and id_rsa.pub are the older key. This key is working fine. But where the second key is needed, i can't login. It trys the first key and fails.

Running this command `ssh-add /Users/kevin/.ssh/id_rsa.gitlab` helps. But after a reboot, it dosen't work anymore and i must run the command again.

Is there a better solution as run this command after each reboot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to use several ssh keys is to use a ~/.ssh/config

```
Host serverKey1
   Hostname server1 # or ip address of server1
   User serverUser
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host serverKey2
   Hostname server1 # or ip address of server1
   User serverUser
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.gitlab
```

You then need to use an scp-syntax for your ssh url:

```
git clone serverKey1:/my/repo
git clone serverKey2:/my/repo
```

`serverKey1` and `serverKey2` are entries in your `~/.ssh/config` file in order to pass to ssh the right server, user and identify file (public and private keys)

If those private keys are password-protected, [you would still need to add them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1909651/6309).

You can see more at this atlassian help page: "[Configure multiple SSH identities for GitBash, Mac OSX, & Linux](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=271943168)".