# How can I have multiple git accounts on a single development machine?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, multi-user

I am trying to work simultaneously on more than one (two or three) GitLab (or even GitHub) projects on a single development machine. Because upon configuration the IDEs and the git service has the data of my primary user when I try to checkout or clone another project with a different username / password the system says either project is not found or I do not have permissions to do that.

How can I configure and use more than one git user on a single development machine?

Comment: git user can be configured per repository.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple GitHub Accounts & SSH Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225862/multiple-github-accounts-ssh-config)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple git user in single device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50304606/multiple-git-user-in-single-device)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store your credentials in each project using.

```
git config credential.helper store
git push origin HEAD
write user and password
```

Go to the project folder and type the git commands.

Comment: Won't work if you have many remotes in one repo.

Answer (score 13):

By default, git is using a system-wide configuration file or the one stored at top of your home directory.

But you can also set a file `.git/config` inside each repository, either by editing manually or using `git config`. Inside, you may specify the following sections :

```
[user]
    name = Your name
    email = yourownemail@yourprovider.com

…

[credential "<your_project_hoster_url>"]
    username = <username to log in with>
```

You can check [git config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) in general or [git credentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) in particular for more information about it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Finally I found the culprit of Git using the wrong username from my `~\.git-credentials` (from the first line, but not from the second one). So I just set this setting locally: `git config credential.username my-2nd-username`, and it worked fine. Thank you.

Comment: Fantastic!! I have been searching how to be able to talk to multiple git repos on the same machine, this works seamlessly with the [credential} tip key for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can configure your user details per repository.

```
git config user.name 'Your Name'
git config user.email 'name@example.com'
```

GitHub can be configured to recognise several ssh keys assigned to email addresses and send email messages to the corresponding ones when needed.

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer https instead of the SSH key solutions, the following works on Windows at least for Github (and in connection with TortoiseGit using a credential manager):

1. In your local repository (or while cloning), set the remote (origin) url to

```
https://[yourusername]@github.com/[org]/[repo].git
```

(The important part here is the *yourusername@github.com* as this creates a `git:https://yourusername@github.com` entry in the Windows credential store that differs from the regular `git:https://github.com` entry that holds the credentials for all "regular" remote urls)

In case you want to edit it for an existing repository via the `repo/.git/config` file, this is something like

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://[yourusername]@github.com/[org]/[repo].git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

2. Additionally, set the `credential` and `user` properties in the `repo/.git/config` file so your commits have the correct author:

```
[credential]
   username = [Github-Username]
[user]
   name = [Fullname]
   email = [Email Address]
```

At your git remote operation (fetch, push etc.), you will be asked for authentication depending on your auth manager.

Answer (score 1):

## Git multiple user config manager [gum](https://github.com/gauseen/gum)

### Install

```sh
$ npm i -g @gauseen/gum
```

### Example

```sh
$ gum list

Currently used name=gauseen email=gauseen@gmail.com
┌────────────┬─────────┬─────────────────────────┐
│ group-name │    name │                   email │
├────────────┼─────────┼─────────────────────────┤
│    global  │ gauseen │ gauseen@gmail.com       │
│    user1   │ li si   │ lisi@gmail.com          │
│    user2   │ wang er │ wanger@gmail.com        │
└────────────┴─────────┴─────────────────────────┘
$ gum use user1

Currently used name=li si email=lisi@gmail.com
```