# Run ssh-askpass in Cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm trying to run the `SSHFS` command in Cocoa app. I already put the SSHFS command in `NSTask` and but i got some error when executing the command:

```
RSA host key for IP address 'xyz.com' not in list of known hosts.

ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory

Permission denied, please try again.

ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory

Permission denied, please try again.

ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory

Permission denied (publickey,password).

remote host has disconnected

mount_osxfusefs: failed to mount /Volumes/Drive_Test@/dev/osxfuse4: Socket is not connected
```

In this case i think my app cannot find out the `ssh_askpass`. My question is how to run this file? Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: first things is to make sure the file exists. If not, please install it and try again. It should be part of `openssh-clients` package

Comment: @Jakuje Er… this is Mac OS, not Linux.

Comment: @duskwuff: Yes, it's OSX. Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`ssh-askpass` is an X11 application which is not directly compatible with MacOS.  You can install a custom `ssh-askpass` in the same path, though it's a bit of a hack. [Here](https://github.com/jcs/openssh-mac) is one implementation, though I can't vouch for its integrity or security, or compatibility with current MacOS. (See also blog at https://jcs.org/notaweblog/2011/04/19/making_openssh_on_mac_os_x_more_secure by the same author with forays into other possible approaches.)

A better and more modern solution is to let the MacOS keychain handle things for you.  See e.g. [SVN+SSH, not having to do ssh-add every time? (Mac OS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909651/svnssh-not-having-to-do-ssh-add-every-time-mac-os) (not just for SVN obviously).